# Optimize update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for suggestions to optimize this query that already runs for over an hour with about 300,000 rows in the table. We are using a reporting tool that requires data to be in this shape when it's pulled, so re-designing table structure is not an option. The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [datatable](
    [RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CampaignID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CampaignName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [PostID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TopicName] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [TopicFrequency] [int] NULL
)
```

Data is being constantly added to the table, so I have to periodically update topic frequencies. Here is my current query:

```
UPDATE  datatable
SET     TopicFrequency = b.TopicFrequency
FROM    datatable INNER JOIN
  (SELECT CampaignID, Category, TopicName, COUNT(DISTINCT PostID) AS TopicFrequency
    FROM datatable GROUP BY CampaignID, Category, TopicName) AS b 
    ON datatable.CampaignID = b.CampaignID 
    AND datatable.Category = b.Category 
    AND datatable.TopicName = b.TopicName
```

With topic name being nvarchar 4000 I can't create an index on the field. Looking for ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Have you examined the execution plan for the query to locate the bottleneck?  An index that combines both CampaignID and Category columns may help.  And you may want to add a tag to your question to specify the database you're using, e.g. sql-server-2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General decision - is to split your table into two or more tables - ie - normalize the data structure. I think that two more tables can be introduced - for Campaigns and Topics

**BUT**

For your present data structures you can create an `uniqueidentifier` or `bigint` computed column as hash of `TopicName` field, index it and look for hash instead of string field. I'll provide you an example with `bigint`:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[HashString64SVF](@input NVARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS BIGINT
WITH SCHEMABINDING, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT 
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN
        CAST(SUBSTRING(HASHBYTES('SHA1', UPPER(@Input)), 1, 8) AS BIGINT) 
    ^   CAST(SUBSTRING(HASHBYTES('SHA1', UPPER(@Input)), 9, 8) AS BIGINT) 
    ^   CAST(SUBSTRING(HASHBYTES('SHA1', UPPER(@Input)), 17, 4) AS BIGINT) 
END
GO
ALTER TABLE datatable ADD TopicNameHash AS dbo.HashString64SVF(TopicName)
GO
CREATE INDEX NewIndexName ON DataTable(TopicNameHash, CampaignID, Category) INCLUDE(PostId)
GO
UPDATE  datatable
SET     TopicFrequency = b.TopicFrequency
FROM    datatable 
JOIN
  (SELECT CampaignID, Category, TopicNameHash, COUNT(DISTINCT PostID) AS TopicFrequency
    FROM datatable GROUP BY CampaignID, Category, TopicNameHash) AS b 
    ON datatable.CampaignID = b.CampaignID 
    AND datatable.Category = b.Category 
    AND datatable.TopicNameHash = b.TopicNameHash
```

**AND**

Create a primary key on RowId column

**AND**

Recreate the table in way like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [datatable](
    [RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [CampaignID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [PostID] [int] NOT NULL,
    --uncomment if needed [TopicNameHash] AS dbo.HashString64SVF(TopicName),
    [TopicFrequency] [int] NULL,
    [CampaignName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [TopicName] [nvarchar](4000) NULL
)
```

The main reason - if your nullable variable columns is in the end of columns list and there are many `NULL` values in these columns - sql server can save a little space in row and thus - in IO

Answer (score 0):

**Trigger**

Update frequency field as data is inserted/updated/deleted?  Spreads load over time, and the only records that get updated are the ones relevant to changed data.

**TopicID**

Have a Topic table, which may or may not have more than just `id, name`.  You can then use (and index on) the TopicID instead.

As you have TopicName in both a GROUP BY and the JOIN, being able to index this will make a *massive* performance difference.

**LastModified or other Audit Track**

Record (and include in an index) the last modified time, or some other audit tracking.  This will enable you to narrow the scope of the update to just Topics which have had records inserted/updated/deleted since the last batch process.

**Normalisation**

Keep the Frequency value in another table, keyed by Campaign, Category, Topic.

At present, if your COUNT(*) yields 100, you're updating 100 records.  Normalisation will mean one update per group.

**Obvious Note?**

Just because you normalise or refactor the underlying data, you're not (surely?) prevented from replacing this table with a view onto a 'better' designed structure?

The reporting tool reads the view as if it were a table.  The data processing interacts directly with the refactored table structure, in a *much* more efficient manner.

Separation of data reporting considerations and data processing considerations will make you a much more free person.

Answer (score 0):

If you could avoid corelated subquery to update it, I think it will improve the performance. Why don't you directly join your table and update the table. see [this](http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2009/06/correlated-sub-queries-for-good-or-evil.html) link

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue some time ago: Thirdparty software was using the table that was too big for some data manipulation. Trick I made to resolve the problem was to:

1. create optimized table structure and copy data from old table
2. Delete old table
3. Create view with the same name as deleted table that uses optimized structure and has same structure as old table

For thirdparty software there was no difference between table and view.

You can also add triggers on view to make it updatable.